# How do you pass 1 or 2 or no arguments to ReactJS Functional component using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

this is my code:

```
interface GetMarketingContentProps {
  modules?: object[]
  filter?: string
}

const getMarketingContent: React.FunctionComponent<GetMarketingContentProps> = ({
  modules = null, filter = ''
}: GetMarketingContentProps) => {
```

I am trying to pass either 1 or 2 or no arguments. How can I make this happen? I am using of course TypeScript with reactJS.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are props and are always a single object. That object could be empty. What have you tried so far?

Comment: A functional component's props are _always_ one argument: a single object. The object's properties can be optional, which you have specified in your interface. What issues do you have with your current implementation?

Comment: current implementation when I pass no arguments it complains, and tells me there should be 1 or more arguments passed. is the only way for me to do this is to use a spread operator? and test if arguments [0] or [1] exist?